# error installing Native Base for React Native

Tags: react-native, installation, native-base

I installed Native Base on one machine and this was fast and no hiccups, but it fails on another machine. Below is the log of what happens, can somebody please advise. 
I just reinstalled git to the latest version.
Thank you.

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:272:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (internal/childprocess.js:220:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit git+://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.git resetting remote C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-git-8603b9f3 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:272:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (internal/childprocess.js:220:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:272:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (internal/childprocess.js:220:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit git+://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git resetting remote C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:272:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (internal/childprocess.js:220:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d: fatal: unable to access '://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d: CAfile: D:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d: CApath: none
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-git-8603b9f3: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-git-8603b9f3'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-git-8603b9f3: fatal: unable to access '://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-git-8603b9f3: CAfile: D:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-git-8603b9f3: CApath: none
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror ://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git--github-com-GeekyAnts-react-native-drawer-git-5dbe324d'...npm ERR! fatal: unable to access '://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-drawer.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
npm ERR! CAfile: D:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
npm ERR! CApath: none
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-11T19_31_31_038Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Probably issue with git on your system

Comment: Tried installing native-base with git version 2.15.1 in Mac. Didn't see any issue.